# How can I diagnose and resolve noises from my ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Over the past couple nights my bedroom fan has produced different noises. Originally the noise was from the light and fan pull chains colliding. Now there seems to be a new sound every night. Each more frustrating than the last. The sounds are only audible when the fan is on high.

Last night's sounds seemed to tick every second 6 times, then stop for two "beats" and start again. The night prior it seemed to be on a 4 ticks of varying loudness, followed by a short break and 2 more. Then a "I think it's done being annoying and I can finally fall asleep" period and it would start again.

When the fan is on medium or low, it does not produce the desired room temperature. What are some things I can do to find the cause of the ceiling fan noises?

Comment: Most likely you need to tighten some screws. Take it apart a bit, ensure it's firmly mounted to the ceiling. If it's still noisy try isolating various parts. If it's STILL noisy run to the hardware store and desperately impulse-buy a new fan. :)

Comment: I had a similar problem when the fan was close to a vent and every time the furnace blower kicked on it would throw the blades a bit out of balance causing the tick. In my case changing the direction of the louvers solved it.

Comment: sounds like oscillations building up from unbalanced blades. you can tape coins to the back of the misfit blade (or it's opposite) to stabilize the whole unit. there's some complicated way to tell which one needs taped, but it's easy to try them all and play better/worse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I was not looking in the right place. The problem was the light fixture was not screwed in tightly. After tightening all the blades I tried the fixture and the noises are gone.